# Dematerialize in RxJava2 only returns Object type Observable

Tags: java, rx-java2

When using dematerialize, the Observable returned by .dematerialize() is always of type Object, and not my original type.
Example here (using IntelliJ in an Android Project)

```
import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.observers.TestObserver;

public class RxTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Observable<String> wrongObservable = ((Observable<String>) Observable.just("Test").materialize().dematerialize());
        Observable<String> castedObservable = Observable.just("Test").materialize().dematerialize().map(i -> (String)i);
        TestObserver<String> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
        castedObservable.subscribe(testObserver);
        testObserver.assertValueCount(1);
        testObserver.assertValue("Test");

    }

}
```

This code will show an error at the first line of the test function

```
error: incompatible types: Observable<Object> cannot be converted to Observable<String>
```

If I do the cast in a map-call afterwards (as shown in the next line) everything seems to work fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just force the desired type argument via `.<String>dematerialize()` and it should work. Java doesn't allow us to have instance methods that only show up when the parent class' type arguments are of a specific shape, hence the type disconnect.

Comment: This solved it for me, will post is as an answer in case others stumble on this

Answer (score 1):

As explained in a comment by *akarnokd*, this is a limitation of Java.
It can be solved by adding the type argument such as:

```
.<String>dematerialize()
```